# OpenID and OAuth not working

Tags: oauth, openid

The following link from googlecodesamples is working.

Note: Since I can only have 2 links, I can't point to my sources

Question stackover google-hybrid-openidoauth-login-not-prompting-for-oauth-access

and developers_google_com/accounts/docs/OpenID

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php
&openid.realm=http://googlecodesamples.com&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0
&openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request
&openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email
&openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
&openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last
&openid.ext1.required=email,first,last
&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
&openid.oauth.consumer=googlecodesamples.com
&openid.oauth.scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
```

above [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php&openid.realm=http://googlecodesamples.com&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0&openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&openid.ext1.required=email,first,last&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.oauth.consumer=googlecodesamples.com&openid.oauth.scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/)

It takes you to a login/confirmation and return a blank page, but the replying url is correct as follows:

```
http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php?
openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
openid.mode=id_res
openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
openid.response_nonce=2012-08-02T22:51:28ZNuhXnuA5P14fcg
openid.return_to=http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/index.php
openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9XA_khrLenZI2mnUwkI1PWV-7ERMRXskVzs_nlFhq87rO0iowVL
openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,
  assoc_handle,ns.ext1,ns.ext2,ext1.mode,ext1.type.first,ext1.value.first,
  ext1.type.email,ext1.value.email,ext1.type.last,ext1.value.last,ext2.scope,
  ext2.request_token
openid.sig=JFoYU7PM4GoKBODmLyMtip5q7x4=
openid.identity=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlvAimmJ5_y6-gMro7Xyl75LXMC7jYCkiA
openid.claimed_id=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlvAimmJ5_y6-gMro7Xyl75LXMC7jYCkiA
openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response
openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
openid.ext1.value.first=nico
openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email
openid.ext1.value.email=nico.gtest@gmail.com
openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last
openid.ext1.value.last=gtest
openid.ns.ext2=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
openid.ext2.scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
openid.ext2.request_token=4/vAQqXlNILhAC0KCIBS2xlhtpo0IT.4lllxzFP7ncSgrKXntQAax2gXBbTcQI
```

where the important part is the **openid.ext2.request_token** witch is present in the reply

but if I change the link to my info the reply don't have **ANY oauth fields**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://dev.oncrm.co.za:9004/gauthapp/myserv?test_v=verify_dbug
&openid.realm=http://dev.oncrm.co.za:9004
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0
&openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request
&openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email
&openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
&openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last
&openid.ext1.required=email,first,last
&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
&openid.oauth.consumer=dev.oncrm.co.za:9004
&openid.oauth.scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
```

above [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=http://dev.oncrm.co.za:9004/gauthapp/myserv?test_v=verify_dbug&openid.realm=http://dev.oncrm.co.za:9004&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0&openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.ext1.type.first=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&openid.ext1.type.last=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&openid.ext1.required=email,first,last&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.oauth.consumer=dev.oncrm.co.za:9004&openid.oauth.scope=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/)

I have registered my domain at google console

Created a Client ID and Client secret , witch is not used in the url's of any of the samples ???

Switch on all API services

the **openid.realm == openid.oauth.consumer** same as the sample

The openID part work, but can't get google to return the **openid.ext2.request_token**
, so I can continue to request the access_token

I also used the openid4java API (with oauth extention, issue 110), with no success on oauth

The questions

a) Why is my link not working, what else must I do

b) What is the idea of Client ID and Client secret if it is not used

c) The parameter: openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
   is also bugging me, is the openID+OAuth working on oauth1.0 or oauth2.0

PLEASE ANY HELP would be appreciated

thanks nico

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anywhere in the documentation where Google states that the OpenId + OAuth works with OAuth 2.0. All their documentation points to the 1.0 OAuth and I haven't seen any statements from Google saying that it works with 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark notes, you can't do OpenID + OAuth with OAuth 2.0 yet, only 1.0. I do think 1.0 will work for the scope you're requesting, though, and it may be worth using it over 2.0 if it means eliminating a second authorization step for the user.

Assuming 1.0 works for you, I think the problem with your link is that you need to register your domain using Google's "Manage your domains" tool (https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains), not the API console. The API console is, as far as I can tell, exclusively for OAuth 2.0.

Assuming my hunch is right, that answers (a) and (c), albeit in reverse order. As for (b), the client ID I believe gets used only in OAuth 2.0. The client secret, which exists in 1.0 and 2.0, is used to sign your request for an *access* token, which you do after receiving the request token. So the process is: (1) get request token (which can be done as part of OpenID auth), (2) exchange request token for access token, (3) use access token to call API.

Hope this answers your questions but let me know if not (or if I'm off-base anywhere). I've been wrestling with this stuff the last few days myself and would be interested to hear how you're faring.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it going with the following API and configs

a) Use (https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains) to setup domain and use (https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth) to create and Upload X.509 cert

b) API openid4java with oauth extension (issue 110)

c) Resources & samples

```
OAuthExample.java from gdata-samples.java-1.47.1
ConsumerServlet.java from openid4java
Sample.java from issue 110
```

d) Use **OAuthRsaSha1Signer** for signing (from a. Upload X.509 cert) then there is no oauthReqTokenSecret or accessTokenSecret witch is required with OAuthHmacSha1Signer

e) Signing also need to be done with ContactsService

**There is still a concern over the deprecation of OAuth1 and if it is not better to wait for openid to work with OAuth2**

> **anyone have an idea when that will be ????**